# How to put XML files to MYSQL and MYSQL files to XML

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put in in to MYSQL and XML files but when i press to put in MYSQL it does that, and when i press to put in XML it puts in to MYSQL. I don't know how to fix that.

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/DuombazesInfo.php'
?>

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['Ikelimas'])) {
$xml = new DOMDocument ("1.0","UTF-8");
$xml -> load("pavyzdysxml.xml");

$rootTag = $xml -> getElementsByTagName ("document") -> item(0);

$dataTag = $xml -> createElement("data");

$nameTag = $xml -> createElement("name", $_REQUEST['name']);
$lastnameTag = $xml -> createElement("lastname", $_REQUEST['lastname']);
$emailTag = $xml -> createElement("email", $_REQUEST['email']);
$passwordTag = $xml -> createElement("password", $_REQUEST['password']);

$dataTag -> appendChild($nameTag);
$dataTag -> appendChild($lastnameTag);
$dataTag -> appendChild($emailTag);
$dataTag -> appendChild($passwordTag);

$rootTag -> appendChild($dataTag);

$xml -> save("PavyzdysXML.xml");
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code from includes/prisijungimas.php? Because the file handles saving

Comment: The title of your question doesn't reflect the content. Try updating it to make it easier for others to understand the question.

Comment: @TomScholz I tried to make it clear. But it didn't let me to put in words like php or html or help or problem

Comment: @TomScholz is it better now?

Comment: Have a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a check to the file includes/prisijungimas.php:

```
<?php
include_once 'DuombazesInfo.php';

//If button with name "Ikelimas" was clicked
if(isset($_REQUEST['Ikelimas'])) { 
   //Generete XML here (code from first message)
   $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
   $xml->load("pavyzdysxml.xml");

   $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName ("document") -> item(0);

   $dataTag = $xml->createElement("data");

   $nameTag = $xml->createElement("name", $_REQUEST['name']);
   $lastnameTag = $xml->createElement("lastname", $_REQUEST['lastname']);
   $emailTag = $xml->createElement("email", $_REQUEST['email']);
   $passwordTag = $xml->createElement("password", $_REQUEST['password']);

   $dataTag->appendChild($nameTag);
   $dataTag->appendChild($lastnameTag);
   $dataTag->appendChild($emailTag);
   $dataTag->appendChild($passwordTag);

   $rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);

   $xml->save("PavyzdysXML.xml");
} else {
   //Insert into DB (code from includes/prisijungimas.php)

   // Kodo eilute skirta apsaugoti duomenis, kad ju negaletu istrinti pasinaudojant formos langais
   $vardas = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
   $pavarde = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
   $pastas = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
   $slaptazodis = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
   $md5pass = md5($slaptazodis);

   // Kodas skirtas įdėti į duomenų bazę duomenis kurie buvo suvesti formoje
   $sql = "INSERT INTO vartotojai1 (vardas, pavarde, pastas, slaptazodis)
   VALUES ('$vardas', '$pavarde', '$pastas ', '$slaptazodis');";
   mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}

header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Comment: so should i delete the code where i posted in first message and put everything to includes/prisijungimas.php ?

Comment: @TautvydasAdomavičius Yes

Comment: What about the form? Should i leave it or delete it too?

Comment: You should have a form. Otherwise, how are you going to get the data?